# How to calculate this equation

Tags: calculus

$⌊\frac{x+1}{2}⌋=\frac{x-1}{3}-1$
I have solve this equation graphically but is there any way to solve without using graph.

Comment: '\lfloor \rfloor' gives you the floor function notation

Answer (score 2):

Using the inequalities $y-1<\lfloor y\rfloor\le y$, a necessary condition is

$$\frac{x+1}{2}-1<\frac{x-1}3-1\le \frac{x+1}{2}\iff -11\le x<-5$$
Now for which $x$ in $[-11,-5)$, $\frac{x-1}3-1$ is an integer?